# how to check for numbers in a string recursively in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to make a script that recursively check for numbers, for example to check if the the two strings have the same amount of a certain digit. This is what I have so far:

```
while(x<9):
    n = str(x)
    if a.count(n) == b.count(n):
        cow=+1    
    x+=1
```

However, this recurs and doesn't return the function that it was in.

Comment: is this academic or practical?

Comment: There is no function in the code you are showing, only a loop, and a loop makes it iterative, not recursive. Maybe you aren't showing us everything?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: 1)academic, 2) its inside a function. 3) i want to be able to check 2 strings with 4 digits each to see if they have any matching digits.

Comment: @windkrieg look into `collections.Counter`

Comment: @windkrieg does having 0 of a certain digit in both strings count as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check how many digits 'x' are in a string you can use this recursive function:

```
def recursive_count(input_str, x):
        if len(input_str) == 0:
             return 0
        tot = 0
        if input_str[0] == str(x):
             tot += 1
        tot += recursive_count(input_str[1:], x)
        return tot
```

How it works:

1. It checks if the string has length 0, this is to terminate the recursive function in the end.
2. If the first number of the string equals the digit you're looking for, it adds 1 to the total count.
3. It then counts the remaining digits in the string (so all the digits after the first one)

If you wish to compare two strings you can use:

```
if recursive_count(string_1, x) == recursive_count(string_2, x):
       foo = bar
```

An example to further explain how this works:

1. Call `recursive_count('121', 1)`
2. because the first digit_1 == 1 count_1 is set to 1 (the _1 indicates it is in the first instance of the function called)
3. Call `recursive_count('21', 1)`
4. The first digit does not equal 1, so count_2 is set to 0
5. Call `recursive_count('1', 1)`
6. The first digit does equal 1, so count_3 is set to 1
7. Call `recursive_count('', 1)`
8. Length of input string == 0 so it returns 0
9. count_3 gets added 0 from `recursive_count('', 1)` and returns 1
10. count_2 gets added 1 from `recursive_count('1', 1)` and returns 1
11. count_1 gets added 1 from `recursive_count('21', 1)` and returns 2
12. `recursive_count('121', 1)` returns 1

If you want to compare if two strings have any digit equally often you can use:

```
import numpy as np

def recursive_count(input_str):
        tot = np.zeros(10)
        if len(input_str) == 0:
             return tot
        tot[int(input_str[0])] += 1
        tot += recursive_count(input_str[1:])
        return tot

def compare_two(input_str_1, input_str_2):
    first_res = recursive_count(input_str_1)
    second_res = recursive_count(input_str_2)
    if any(first_res == second_res):
        print('Strings have at least one integer equally often*')
        print('*This could also be 0 times')
```

If both having zero of a certain digit does not count, you can do something like this (not pretty but best I can come up with for now):

```
    same_digits = [i for i in range(10) if first_res[i] == second_res[i] and first_res[i] != 0]
    if len(same_digits) > 0 :
        print('Strings have {} digits equally often'.format(same_digits))
```

Comment: this seems good, but what I need is to be able to compare 1 string against another to see how many matching digits are in there.

Comment: can't you just compare the output of the function twice?

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant with certain digit, I thought you meant 'one specific digit' but you meant instead 'any one digit'?

Comment: @windkrieg I added functionality to check all digits, and to check if they're present equally often in both strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw it had to be recursive.

This can do the job, but not very efficient:

```
def compare(num_1, num_2): 
     if len(num_1) == 0 or len(num_2) == 0 : return 0
     if num_1[0] == num_2[0]: return 1 + compare(num_1[1:], num_2[1:])
     return max(compare(num_1,num_2[1:]), compare(num_1[1:],num_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a generic `count_chars` function that groups similar chars using addition

```
def count_chars (iter):
  def loop (iter, answer = {}):
    if not iter:
      return list (answer.items ())
    else:
      char, *next = iter
      answer[char] = answer[char] + 1 if char in answer else 1
      return loop (next, answer)
  return loop (iter, {})

print (count_chars ("abbcccdddd"))
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

As you can see, `count_chars` works on any *iterable*, strings included. Now we want a way to take two separate counts and diff them. Here is `count_diff`

```
def count_diff (c1, c2):
  answer = dict (c1)
  for (char, count) in c2:
    answer[char] = answer[char] - count if char in answer else -count
  return [ (char, count) for (char, count) in answer.items () if count != 0 ]

print (count_diff (count_chars ("ab"), count_chars ("bcd")))
# [('a', 1), ('c', -1), ('d', -1)]

print (count_diff (count_chars ("abcz"), count_chars ("bbcccdddd")))
# [('a', 1), ('b', -1), ('c', -2), ('z', 1), ('d', -4)]
```

Above, we can see a count is *positive* when it only appears in the left input `c1`, and it is *negative* when it only appears in the right input `c2`. In other words, a result of `[('a', 1)]` means the left input has `1` more `a` than the right input. A result of `[('c', -2)]` means the right input has `2` more `'c'` than the left input. When a char appears equally in both inputs, it does not appear in the output.

If the inputs are the same, an empty diff is returned

```
str = "abbcccddd123"
print (count_diff (count_chars (str), count_chars (str)))
# []
```

Using this to differentiate 4-digit strings is easy now. Most importantly, notice that order of the digits in the string does not matter

```
def diff_numbers (str1, str2):
  diff = count_diff (count_chars (str1), count_chars (str2))
  return [ (int (char), count) for (char, count) in diff if char.isdigit () ]


print (diff_numbers ("abc123", "abc234"))
# [(1, 1), (4, -1)]

print (diff_numbers ("8888", "8878"))
# [(8, 1), (7, -1)]

print (diff_numbers ("1234", "4231"))
# []
```

---

Because this is an academic question, I show how to write `count_chars` by hand. But if this was a real program, using something like `itertools.groupby` (below) might be better

```
from itertools import groupby

def count_chars (iter):
  return [ (char, len (list (count))) for (char, count) in groupby (iter) ]

def count_diff (c1, c2):
  answer = dict (c1)
  for (char, count) in c2:
    answer[char] = answer[char] - count if char in answer else -count
  return [ (char, count) for (char, count) in answer.items () if count != 0 ]

def diff_numbers (str1, str2):
  diff = count_diff (count_chars (str1), count_chars (str2))
  return [ (int (char), count) for (char, count) in diff if char.isdigit () ]


print (diff_numbers ("abc123", "abc234"))
# [(1, 1), (4, -1)]

print (diff_numbers ("8888", "8878"))
# [(8, 1), (7, -1)]

print (diff_numbers ("1234", "4231"))
# []
```